# Не работает реклама AdMob после билда

Tags: unity3d, admob

Добавляю в игру рекламу Google AdMob. Вот, допустим, код рекламы с вознаграждением

```
using UnityEngine;
```

using GoogleMobileAds.Api;

public class RewardAd: MonoBehaviour {

```
public GameObject playergo;
public GameObject answerbuttongo;

private RewardedAd _rewardad;
private const string _adid = "ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/5224354917";

private RewardedAd _rewardAd;
private const string _adId = "ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/5224354917";
private void OnEnable() {
    _rewardAd = new RewardedAd(_adId);
    AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().Build();
    _rewardAd.LoadAd(adRequest);
    _rewardAd.OnUserEarnedReward += HandleUserEarnedReward;
    }
public void ShowAd() {
    //if(_rewardAd.IsLoaded()) {
        _rewardAd.Show();
    //    }
    }
private void HandleUserEarnedReward(object sender, Reward args) {

    Time.timeScale = 1;
    playergo.GetComponent<Player_Scr>().hp = 100;
    playergo.GetComponent<Player_Scr>().adBool = true;
    answerbuttongo.SetActive(false);


    }
}
```

Запускаю в среде Unity - все работает. Тестовая реклама отображается при нажатии на нужную клавишу, после просмотра и ее закрытия назначается награда.

Когда я создаю файл .apk и закидываю на телефон приложение, эта реклама уже не отображается.

1. Нашел такой лог через Android Studio:

2022-11-18 14:24:01.942 22565-22565/? W/AdsUnity: Rewarded ad is not ready to be shown. Следует вопрос - а как ее предзагружать!?

И вот такой лог, из которого следует, что запрос с тестового устройства. Но реклама не показывается

2022-11-18 14:43:36.995 6014-6014/? D/AdsUnity: Calling loadAd() on Android
2022-11-18 14:43:37.011 6014-6014/? D/DynamitePackage: Instantiating com.google.android.gms.ads.ChimeraAdManagerCreatorImpl
2022-11-18 14:43:37.017 6014-6014/? I/Ads: This request is sent from a test device.
2022-11-18 14:43:48.023 6014-6014/? I/Ads: Ad failed to load : 0

2. Возможно, я что-то делаю не так. Пока у меня висят тестовые ID рекламы, а в настройках запилен ID приложения уже из AdMob'a. Как исправить?

Comment: А зачем ты закоментировал _rewardAd.IsLoaded()

Comment: Сначало проверяется успела ли загрузиться реклама, а потом попытаться показать её

Comment: Для тестовой рекламы это не имеет большого значения, она все равно должна запускаться. В Unity это происходит, а на телефоне - нет

Answer (score 0):

Закинь загрузку рекламы в корутину или в Update, чтобы она загружалась (с нужного тебе момента) пока не загрузится и только потом запускай показ - скорость соединения бывает разная и не всегда все происходит моментально. У меня вообще реклама с вознаграждением упорно не хочет загружаться если я подключен не по wi-fi, а с мобильной связи (хотя соединение и скорость хорошие) - но я еще сам пытаюсь с этим разобраться..